# Do I have to state a temporary furlough on a resume?

Tags: job-search, resume, hiring-process, human-resources, hiring

I am curious: do I have to state my temporary furlough on my resume?

I’ve worked with a company for nearly 5 years. During Covid in 2020 I was furloughed for about 4 months and then brought back. I’ve been with the same company since.

When applying for new jobs, should I list my furlough on my resume? It’s a little odd because I was furloughed and then brought back.

Comment: I would mention it because you don't want to fail a background check with something that was easily explained. If you were furloughed for COVID related reasons, you could just leave a note to mention that.

Comment: I can't imagine any firm would be particularly interested to note that you were furloughed for a brief time, unless it is purely to explain the existence of a second job also mentioned in the CV.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie any advice on how to list it on resume?

Comment: @AccomplishedHall: List the job once, but include two date ranges (use two lines instead of one).  For the record, I agree with BittermanAndy.

Comment: "Do I have to state a temporary furlough on a resume?"  No, there are no laws or regulations about what you put on your resume. Unless you present it as a complete record of your employment history, you can leave things off that aren't helpful to the job of the resume, which is to get you an interview.

Answer (score 9):

**No**, I don't think you need to mention furlough on your resume/CV. (I don't).

I think everyone understands that the world was a very strange place in 2020. Many businesses furloughed staff, many other employees had to work much harder than normal. Of those who were on furlough, some (like me) spent the whole time playing video games - some spent the whole time furthering their education and improving themselves in various ways - others were too busy worrying about how they were going to pay rent or buy groceries or cope without a loved one they'd lost to the illness, to be even thinking about any of those other things.

It was a bad time for a lot of people, and unprecedented for all of us; we all had different experiences, but in terms of your resume / CV, you were an employee of that company for five years, and a few months on furlough aren't any more worthy of note than a few weeks on extended vacation, or time spent on a project that went nowhere. It's just detail.

Answer (score 3):

If you were truly furloughed then you shouldn't put it on your resume. Being furloughed is a type of *leave*, like extended medical leave or any other kind of leave. You're still employed but it just happens to be without pay or work and at the choice of the employer rather than the employee. If you got hit by a car and needed to be on medical leave for a couple of months before returning to your job you wouldn't put that on your resume, or if you saved up your normal leave and took a really long vacation.

If you weren't furloughed but were actually temporarily *laid off* and then re-hired then you probably should reflect that on your resume. You would probably know if that happened as it would normally involve some paperwork letting you know that your employment was being ended, more paperwork to re-hire you when you came back, and everything would be stopped in between (whatever benefits you have like health insurance, etc., returning company property, everything you would expect if someone was let go).